# Failed to install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

When I try to install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator I'm getting an error

> This is what the idea.log shows:

```
2019-12-04 14:16:15,560 [d thread 3]  ERROR - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Android Studio 3.5.2  Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832 
2019-12-04 14:16:15,560 [d thread 3]  ERROR - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - JDK: 1.8.0_202-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2019-12-04 14:16:15,560 [d thread 3]  ERROR - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - OS: Mac OS X 
2019-12-04 14:16:15,560 [d thread 3]  ERROR - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Last Action: ActivateEventLogToolWindow 
2019-12-04 14:16:15,561 [d thread 3]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.1)" failed. 
2019-12-04 14:16:15,561 [d thread 3]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Failed packages: 
2019-12-04 14:16:15,561 [d thread 3]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - - Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager) 
2019-12-04 14:16:18,116 [ thread 19]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/ronsivan/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/package.xml 
2019-12-04 14:16:18,125 [ thread 19]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/ronsivan/Library/Android/sdk/patcher/v4/package.xml 
2019-12-04 14:16:18,131 [ thread 19]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/ronsivan/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/package.xml 
2019-12-04 14:16:18,139 [ thread 19]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/ronsivan/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/package.xml 
2019-12-04 14:16:18,145 [ thread 19]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/ronsivan/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-28/package.xml 
2019-12-04 14:16:18,152 [ thread 19]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/ronsivan/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-29/package.xml 
2019-12-04 14:16:18,159 [ thread 19]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/ronsivan/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-28/default/x86_64/package.xml 
2019-12-04 14:16:18,166 [ thread 19]   INFO - s.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Parsing /Users/ronsivan/Library/Android/sdk/tools/package.xml 
2019-12-04 14:16:21,944 [entQueue-0]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed 
2019-12-04 14:16:22,039 [d thread 3]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 3ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-12-04 14:16:22,142 [d thread 3]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 103ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2019-12-04 14:16:39,163 [Alarm Pool]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 112 ms 
2019-12-04 14:16:50,062 [entQueue-0]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Module: 'app'FacetManager took 44 ms 
2019-12-04 14:16:50,086 [Alarm Pool]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 93 ms
```

[image]

Comment: can you add screenshot to question?

Comment: Once I reinstalled SDK and it went nicely. Is it fresh install?

Comment: @ponkape First time I installed, it was ok, but I deleted it, now trying to install again everything fails

Comment: @MilanTejani sure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem solved, you need to go to SDK manager and update Android Emulator to version 29.3.2 then try to install en SDK manager Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)
and that's it. All working fine again.

[image: Android emulator]